# Excel and Ruby compatibility

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, csv, railscasts

I followed this [Railscasts link for CSV export from Rails](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel)to export my html table (dynamically generated) to xls and it downloads my excel document when I do .xls

However, when I open it in iWork Numbers, I get the following error:

Import Warning - This is a tab delimited document, not a valid Excel document. The data might look different.

I see my source code of the table in the document.

Here is the code I use to generate the table:

```
<table border ="1">
        <tr>enter code here
    <th><%= get_column_name "#{@level1}"%></th>
    <th><%= get_column_name "#{@level2}"%></th>
    <th><%= get_column_name "#{@level3}"%></th>
    <th>abcd</th>
    </tr>
        <% @grp.each do |key, value| %>
            <% value.each do |k2, v2|%>
                <% v2.each do |k3, v3|%>
                        <tr>
                            <td><% if "#{@level1}" == "abcd"  && Person.exists?(key.to_i) %><%= "#{Person.find(key.to_i).get_name}" %><% else %><%= "#{key}" %><% end %></td>
                            <td><% if "#{@level2}" == "abcd"  && Person.exists?(k2.to_i) %><%= "#{Person.find(k2.to_i).get_name}" %><% else %><%= "#{k2}" %><% end %></td>
                            <td><% if "#{@level3}" == "abcd"  && Person.exists?(k3.to_i) %><%= "#{Person.find(k3.to_i).get_name}" %><% else %><%= "#{k3}" %><% end %></td>
                            <td><%= "#{v3.count}" if !v3.nil? %></td>
                        </tr>
                <%end%>
            <%end%>
        <%end%>
</table>
```

Can somebody please tell me if it's the problem with Numbers or something else. I am a student and can't really afford to buy excel just to check this.

Best,

Comment: Any code? How do you write your xls doc?

Comment: Hi @halfelf, I have updated the description with my code.

Comment: I think it's probably just a Numbers issue. However, you should consider making a CSV or TSV instead of relying on Excel's HTML->spreadsheet function, so you can actually view your spreadsheet (and others who don't use Excel). It's very easy to do too -- `<%= row.join("\t") %>` is all you need for a valid TSV row.

Comment: You could take a look at existing gems for writing and parsing Excel .xls data. Here's a [short list](http://www.knight.io/categories/spreadsheets-ruby).

Comment: @jmdeldin Could you please elaborate on that? I am new to rails as well. Thanks!

Comment: @jmdeldin , You were right. It was the problem with Numbers only. I checked it on my friend's computer and it works perfectly fine in Excel!

Comment: @anipendakur: Sorry for the delay. I posted a response to clarify  CSVs and rendering them. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more portable approach is to just generate CSV or TSV (tab-delimited) files. This is definitely a good idea if you don't have Excel and if you don't need to deal with the horrors of XLS[X].

The Railscast you linked to gave one solution using the [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) library. It handles quoting fields for you, which is really nice as we'll see in a bit. I'll outline the manual approach as well:

Let's assume you have this action in your controller:

```
# widget_controller.rb
def index
  @widgets = Widget.ordered_by_name
  respond_to do |format|
    format.csv
  end
end
```

And then something like this in your template will work:

```
<%# index.csv.erb %>
ID,Name
<% @widgets.each do |w| %>
<%= w.id %>,<%= w.name %>
<% end %>
```

Or more succinctly:

```
<%# index.csv.erb %>
<%= %w(ID Name).join(",") %>
<%= @widgets.map { |w| [w.id, w.name].join(",") }.join("\n") %>
```

You will need to take care around quoting. For instance, if `widgets[0].name` returned `foo,bar`, your data would look like:

```
ID,Name
1,foo,bar
2,baz
```

The solution is to just quote the field, or if you don't want to think about this...use `CSV.generate` :).

Comment: thank you for the reply. But, I have a dynamically generated hash every time the page is loaded/refreshed.
I got the picture however. I have to render a view in CSV, pass the hash as a parameter; finally quote the fields before joining. I will try this and see if this works in iWork Numbers.
Thank you :)